# jquery-3.1.1.js:3855 Uncaught TypeError: crsl.carousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider

I'm on Wordpress.
I have troubles. 
I have a carousel with a progress bar, when the progress bar come to 100%, the carousel go forward. No need indicators.

My script work on local but don't work on prod.

```js
<script>
(function( $ ) {

 //Function to animate slider captions 
 function doAnimations( elems ) {
  //Cache the animationend event in a variable
  var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';
  
  elems.each(function () {
   var $this = $(this),
    $animationType = $this.data('animation');
   $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
    $this.removeClass($animationType);
   });
  });
 }
 
 //Variables on page load 
 var $myCarousel = $('#carousel-example-generic'),
  $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
  

 //Animate captions in first slide on page load 
 doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

 
 //Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
 $myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
  doAnimations($animatingElems);
 });  
 
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
      var percent = 0, bar = $('.transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar'), crsl = $('#carousel-example-generic');
   function progressBarCarousel() {
     bar.css({width:percent+'%'});
    percent = percent +0.4;
     if (percent>100) {
         percent=0;
         crsl.carousel('next');
     }      
   }
   crsl.carousel({
       interval: 10000
   }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {});var barInterval = setInterval(progressBarCarousel, 30);

    });



</script>
```

```css
 /* SLIDER */
div#quatre-reference {
    position: absolute;
    top: -62px;
    right: 0;
}
#page-accueil.container-fluid {
 padding: 0;
}
div#slider-accueil {
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.carousel-caption {
    top: 136px;
 font-size: 26px;
    font-family: 'CaviarDreamsBold', Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1.titre-carousel {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: white;
 font-size: 84px;
    font-family: 'CaviarDreamsBold', Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1.titre-carousel:after {
 content: none;
}
.carousel-caption .titre-carousel {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
 animation-delay: 2s;
}
.titre-anime {
 height: 96px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.carousel-caption .content-carousel {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
 animation-delay: 1s;
 font-size: 18px;
}
.content-anime {
 height: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.content-anime p { 
 font-family: 'CaviarDreamsBold', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.carousel-caption .bouton-carousel {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
 animation-delay: 3s;
  color: white;
    font-family: 'CaviarDreamsBold', Arial, sans-serif;
border: 2px solid white;
width: 225px;
margin: auto;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.bouton-anime {
 height: 34px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.image-carousel {
 margin-top: -25px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #19447f;
    width: 0%;
    margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
    border: none;
    z-index: 11;
    position: relative;
}
.transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar-fond {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -21px 0 20px 0;
    border: none;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}
.bouton-anime a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
#block-mini-menu-carousel li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 19%;
 text-align: center;
 background: #ffffff;
 padding: 30px;
}
#block-mini-menu-carousel li a {
 color: black;
 font-family: 'CaviarDreamsBold', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}
#block-mini-menu-carousel.container {
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding:0;
}
#block-mini-menu-carousel .nav-menu {
    margin-bottom: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}
#block-mini-menu-carousel li#menu-item-268 a {
    padding: 0;
  animation: mouvementFleche 1s ease infinite;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
.carousel-caption {
 text-shadow: none;
}

@keyframes mouvementFleche {
  0 {
    top: -5px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 5px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -5px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 #block-mini-menu-carousel.container {
  background: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  top: -244px;
 }
 li#menu-item-268 {
  background: transparent;
     position: absolute;
     top: 115px;
     right: calc(50vw - 23%);
     width: 40px;
 }
 #block-mini-menu-carousel li {
     padding: 10px 0;
     width: 47%;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
     margin-right: 5px;
 }
 #block-mini-menu-carousel.container {
     display: block;
 }
 ul#block-mini-menu-carousel {
     padding: 15px 0 0 0;
 }
 .carousel-caption {
  top: 25px;
 }
 h1.titre-carousel {
  font-size: 38px;
 }
 div.titre-anime {
  height: 55px;
 }

}
.carousel-inner>.item>img {
 min-width: 100%;
 height: calc(100vh - 50px);
 min-height: 590px;
}
.article-grand .voir-article {
     position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 0;
}
.info-actu-sidebar.text-center {
    height: 101px;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="slider-accueil" id='slider-accueil'>
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<a id="brand-home" href="<?php get_home_url();?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/img/logo-port-plaisance-la-rochelle.png" alt=""></a>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(4); ?>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="image-carousel"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/img/arriver.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="content-anime"><p class="content-carousel"  data-animation="animated slideInUp"><?php echo do_shortcode( get_post_field('post_content', 4) ); ?></p></div>
        <hr class="transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar" />       
        <hr class="transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar-fond" />
       <div class="titre-anime"><h1 class="titre-carousel" data-animation="animated slideInUp"><?php echo get_the_title(4); ?></h1></div>
<div class="bouton-anime"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(4); ?>"><p class="bouton-carousel"  data-animation="animated slideInUp"><?php  echo __('Toutes nos rubriques') ; ?></p></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(6 ); ?>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="image-carousel"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/img/decouvrir.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="content-anime"><p class="content-carousel"  data-animation="animated slideInUp"><?php echo do_shortcode( get_post_field('post_content', 6) ); ?></p></div>
        <hr class="transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar" />        
        <hr class="transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar-fond" />
       <div class="titre-anime"><h1 class="titre-carousel" data-animation="animated slideInUp"><?php echo get_the_title(6); ?></h1></div>
<div class="bouton-anime"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(6); ?>"><p class="bouton-carousel"  data-animation="animated slideInUp"><?php  echo __('Toutes nos rubriques') ; ?></p></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="item">
      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(8); ?>
      <div class="carousel-caption">   
        <div class="image-carousel"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/img/sedivertir.png" alt=""></div>     
        <div class="content-anime"><p class="content-carousel"  data-animation="animated slideInUp"><?php echo do_shortcode( get_post_field('post_content', 8) ); ?></p></div>
        <hr class="transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar" />
       <hr class="transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar-fond" />
       <div class="titre-anime"><h1 class="titre-carousel" data-animation="animated slideInUp"><?php echo get_the_title(8); ?></h1></div>
        <div class="bouton-anime"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(8); ?>"><p class="bouton-carousel"  data-animation="animated slideInUp"><?php echo __('Toutes nos rubriques') ; ?></p></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(10); ?>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="image-carousel"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/img/sinformer.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="content-anime"><p class="content-carousel"  data-animation="animated slideInUp"><?php echo do_shortcode( get_post_field('post_content', 10) ); ?></p></div>
        <hr class="transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar" />
        <hr class="transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar-fond" />
       <div class="titre-anime"><h1 class="titre-carousel"  data-animation="animated slideInUp"><?php echo get_the_title(10); ?></h1></div>
<div class="bouton-anime"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(10); ?>"><p class="bouton-carousel"  data-animation="animated slideInUp"><?php  echo __('Toutes nos rubriques') ; ?></p></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Someone have a solution for me ?

(sorry for my english)

Comment: where do you create this `crsl` variable?

Comment: @madalinivascu it's defined in the code, at least as it is right now.